# Issue With Nuget Restore - Cannot download certain package from Nuget Feed

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

We have Nuget Feed configured and uploaded all necessary packages to that feed. We also enabled Nuget Restore and Build is downloading packages from that Feed to Build server Nuget cache.
Then Builds solution against packages it depend on. But we begin seeing this issue with one particular package which is not being downloaded during Build process but all other packages do even it is properly defined in packages config file. 
What could be a reason for Team Build (TFS 2013) not being able to download certain Nuget Package from Nuget feed when it is downloads all other packages from same feed?

Comment: Could you provide some more info, please? THe name of the problematic package, the error message from TFS, etc.

Comment: We get only one error saying: "Unable to find version '3.25.25256.12396' of package 'Applications.helpdomain.client.entities'. I assume the error states that package (Applications.helpdomain.client.entities.3.25.25256.12396.nupkg) does not appear in Nuget cache on Build server because I can see that package on the Nuget feed.

Comment: You'll need to check the NuGet caches on the TFS server and use `nuget.exe` to diagnose the issues. Without more detailed information about your setup it's difficult to say more.

Comment: I will try to do that but I don't think the issue is with cache or server as I can see other packages are getting downloaded from same feed and to nuget cache on same build server. Only that package is not getting downloaded.

Comment: Okay, Get Fiddler on this case too for diagnosing HTTP issues: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler